# Looping through several Stata files

Tags: stata

I have around 40 `.dta` files, all containing the same variables but for different units of observations. I want to use Stata to loop through the directory where I have all 40 files to do the following:

1. Load each file into Stata and then export into an Excel sheet. The idea is to have one Excel workbook, with 40 sheets - one per .dta file.
2. In each of the 40 files, count the number of number of distinct observations for the variable named `car_type`. The output can be saved into a different Excel sheet than for 1. But I'm open for suggestions.

I have never worked with `local` or loops before so any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm aware that for step 1 I could write a `do` file with `use "C:\File1.dta` and then `export excel using "C:\Workbook.xlsx", sheet("File1") firstrow(variables) replace` for each file, but I don't want to repeat this manually one-by-one for each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this as a template to get started:

```
set more off

/* (A) Create 5 Fake Datasets file1,...,file5 */ 
sysuse auto, clear

forvalues i=1/5 {
    preserve
        keep if rep78==`i'
        tab rep78
        save "file`i'.dta", replace
    restore
}


/* (B) Export Fake Files to Excel */
capture erase "my_excel_file.xls" // erase Excel file if it exists

ssc install distinct
ssc install fs

fs "file*.dta" // get a list of files to export to Excel

/* loop over this list, opening each one, calculate distinct values, and put the data below that */
foreach f in `r(files)' {
    quietly {
        use "`f'", clear
        distinct make
        generate distinct_vals_of_make = r(ndistinct) in 1
        export excel distinct_vals_of_make using "my_excel_file", sheet("`f'") firstrow(variables) cell(A1)
        drop distinct_vals_of_make
        export excel using "my_excel_file", sheet("`f'", modify) firstrow(variables) cell(A4)
    }
}

shell open "my_excel_file.xls"
```

---

**Answers:**

r(files) is the name of the local macro that contains the list of the files returned by `fs`. When you surround the name with a back quote and an end quote, r(files) will spit out that list. "foreach f in" is just a way to refer to each element of that list as you loop over them sequentially. You could have written "foreach file_name in" just as well. Each time the loop iterates, f (or file_name) will be redefined to contain the next file, which can be obtained with back quote plus f plus end quote. `in 1` means in the first row of the Stata data set.

Finally, I think you can do that with

```
   /* loop over this list, opening each one, calculate distinct values, update the stats sheet, and put the data in a seprate sheet */
/* Initialize the names */
gen file_name=.
gen distinct_vals_of_make=. 
export excel file_name distinct_vals_of_make using "my_excel_file", sheet("stats") firstrow(variables)
local j=2

foreach f in `r(files)' {
    quietly {
        use "`f'", clear
        gen file_name = "`f'" in 1  
        distinct make
        generate distinct_vals_of_make = r(ndistinct) in 1
        export excel file_name distinct_vals_of_make using "my_excel_file", sheet("stats", modify) cell(A`j')
        local ++j

        drop distinct_vals_of_make file_name
        export excel using "my_excel_file", sheet("`f'") firstrow(variables)
    }
}
```

Comment: The latest version of `distinct` is downloadable from the _Stata Journal_ website. `search distinct` in an up-to-date Stata.

Comment: Thanks for the code. It worked great! I want to learn more about it, so I had some questions. In `foreach f in  r(files) { ` what do `f` and the `r(files` scalar stand for? Also, in `generate distinct_vals_of_make = r(ndistinct) in 1` what does the `1` refer to? Lastly, I tried to modify the code to have the results of the distinct value count, appear (along with the file name) in one Excel sheet (i.e. one file name and count per row), but failed miserable. Any tips?

Comment: @StatsScared I edited the post with answers. The backquote messes up the formatting here, so it's a bit clunky.

Comment: @Dimitriy V. Masterov. Thanks for the explanation and help. Regarding the last sentence of my previous comment, I did not explain myself correctly. Let me try again. The final result I'm after is a workbook that has an intial summary sheet where within this same sheet one can see the name of each dta file while and the count of distinct values for the specified variable (which is the same across all dta's). The rest of sheets in the workbook would be the output of the first set of code you provided. Thanks again.

Comment: @Dimitriy V. Masterov. I used your second code earlier and modified to fit my needs. It worked great. However, I lost the .do file I prepared using your codes, so have to re-modify and re-code it again! One issue: I can't recall whether the code in your edit was supposed to be used together with the 1st code you pasted, or if it can be used standalone (e.g. creates the excel sheets for each .dta file AND creates the summary file). In the case both codes must be used together, in what part of the 1st code must I paste the 2nd code? Thanks a lot (again!)

Comment: @StatsScared The part in the Answer *replaces* the chunk of code in between the `fs` and the `shell` in the original answer.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov. Excellent, thank you again for your help.